# Invalid result page when click on search result item

Tags: java, android, search, arraylist

ArrayList custom class

```
ArrayList<ItemClass> nomenclatureList
```

There is the onItemClickListener for it

```
   listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
        ItemClass word = nomenclatureList.get(position);
        int singleImg = word.getImageResourse();
        String singleName = word.getNomenclatureName();
        String singleWeight = word.getNomenclatureWeight();
        String singleBrand = word.getNomeclatureBrand();
        String singleBar = word.getNomenclatureBarCode();
        String singlePercent = word.getNomenclaturePercent();
        String singleComposition = word.getNomenclatureComposition();
        String singlePack = word.getNomenclaturePack();
        Intent intent = new Intent(ItemListGKI.this, ItemSingle.class);
        intent.putExtra("SINGLE_IMG_KEY", singleImg);
        intent.putExtra("SINGLE_NAME_KEY", singleName);
        intent.putExtra("SINGLE_WEIGHT_KEY", singleWeight);
        intent.putExtra("SINGLE_BRAND_KEY", singleBrand);
        intent.putExtra("SINGLE_BAR_KEY", singleBar);
        intent.putExtra("SINGLE_PERCENT_KEY", singlePercent);
        intent.putExtra("SINGLE_COMPOSITION_KEY", singleComposition);
        intent.putExtra("SINGLE_PACK_KEY", singlePack);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

And there is code for search from this ArrayList

```
    @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            boolean success = false;
            ArrayList<String> tempList = new ArrayList<>();
            for(ItemClass temp : nomenclatureList){
                if(temp.getNomenclatureName().toLowerCase().contains(newText.toLowerCase())){
                    tempList.add(temp.getNomenclatureName());
                    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(ItemListGKI.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, tempList);
                    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
                    tempList.size();
                    success = true;
                }
            }
        return success;
    }
```

And when I click on search result item opened activity with wrong information. If I click on item without using search - all is OK.

I don't know what I must to do for fix it.

Comment: Where I must to put it?

Comment: adapterView.getAdapter().getItem(position) Not working.

Comment: I have added a new solution , and I think it will work now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace This :

```
ItemClass word = nomenclatureList.get(position);
```

with this

```
ItemClass word = (ItemClass) adapterView.getItemAtPosition(position);
```

Why? because nomenclatureList has different data than the set adapter when you have searched or filtered the data so `nomenclatureList.get(5)` for example is different than `(ItemClass) adapterView.getItemAtPosition(position);`

Now in onQueryTextChange you should put:

```
 @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            boolean success = false;
            ArrayList<ItemClass> tempList = new ArrayList<>();
            for(ItemClass temp : nomenclatureList){
                if(temp.getNomenclatureName().toLowerCase().contains(newText.toLowerCase())){
                    tempList.add(temp);
                }
            }
             ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(ItemListGKI.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, tempList);
             listView.setAdapter(adapter);
             tempList.size();
             if(tempList.size() > 0){
                success = true;
            }
        return success;
    }
```

Comment: With ItemClass word = (ItemClass) adapterView.getItemAtPosition(position) app crash when I click on search  - item. java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to ru.renna.amkk.ItemClass at ru.renna.amkk.ItemListGKI$1.onItemClick(ItemListGKI.java:147)

Comment: oh that means that is working , i will tell you why with a solution

Comment: the error was because you were  making array of strings here                 `tempList.add(temp.getNomenclatureName());` and you need array of ItemClasses to make this work `ItemClass word = (ItemClass) adapterView.getItemAtPosition(position);` because as you see it takes an item class not a String @АртемИльинский

Comment: So, it's very complicated for me now... I'm in java about 2 weeks. Thank you very much for help, but I'm already uncomfortable asking you for help.

Comment: just try the above and it will work :) and you are most welcome

Comment: I'm fixed it! After one day of relax, I writed right code for 30 minut :) I'm writed new Adapter for click on search button and give data for it from first Adapter.

Comment: oh that's great i am so happy for you and that's good because u r always trying to improve it! :) and yes here we try to help as much as we can because we don't know the structure and how is the data etc... and Goodluckk

Answer (score 0):

As per the API defined here -> https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemClickListener

```
onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id)
```

Your code is considering `position` for retrieving the item being clicked. I believe it should be the id. Try replacing

```
ItemClass word = nomenclatureList.get(position);
```

with

```
ItemClass word = nomenclatureList.get(id);
```

Comment: "cannot be applied for long"

Comment: then convert that long `id` to int using `new Long(id).intValue()`. This is because you are using an ArrayList to store information. There is no loss of information here because max size of ArrayList is Integer.MAX_VALUE.